# PHP Comparison for one less than

Tags: php, comparison, operators

Google really let me down for this one. I want to do a comparison for less than or greater than but only by 1. So I can detect if say value B is one less than or one greater than A.

```
if (A is one less than B || A is one greater than B) {
 return true
}
```

That's what I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want to check if its one above or one below, differentiate the two, and see if the absolute value of the result is one.

```
if (abs($a - $b) === 1) {
    // Do your thing
}
```

See this [live demo](https://3v4l.org/qZ5IR).

Answer (score 2):

Do a standard equality test.

Just perform the subtraction or addition on the value you're comparing to.

```
3 === (4-1)
```

Comment: This is not correct. let say A = 3 and B = 4. op ask to check if $B less or greater than A by 1. So if B =2, op want to be true but this algo will return false.

Comment: @MuhammadAzizolAminuddin — The other side of the `||` was left as a trivial and obvious exercise for the reader.

Comment: Agree, But best to mention there are second part so new programmer know there another part of it.

Comment: It should probably have both for completion. It should detect if anything is one less than or greater than the value.

Comment: @Hasen — Feel free to edit it if you think it needs to spoonfeed the whole thing instead of just explaining the principles. It **is** community wiki.

Comment: It's alright there were much better answers below anyway. I already chose another.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this. As long as the different between `$a` and `$b` is `1`.

```
if(abs($a - $n) == 1) {...}
```

Answer (score -1):

Translating your pseudo condition:

```
(A is one less than B) or (A is one greater than B)
```

this becomes:

```
if ( $A === $B-1 || $A === $B+1 ) {
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but that tenrary operator causes more confusion than it solves. It also needs parenthesis around each sub-group to properly work.

Comment: @Qirel the parenthesis wasnt needed, I've tested it before posting. But i agree, ternary could be more difficult to understand, it looked messy.